# How to print out just the max number from a list of an array?

Tags: java

I have a sequence of words in a text file for my project. I'm trying to distinguish the Capital letters from the file, and only print out the biggest number that it can find. for example Input:
    Roll Tide Roll
    and my Output: 2 R

I think there is code for finding the max count or something, but I'm lost as of now.

Here is my code I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class letters {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
      String str = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println(str);

      int upperCaseCounter = 0;

      int upperCase[] = new int[26];

      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         String s = scanner.nextLine();
         for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
               if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                  upperCase[ch - 'A']++;
                  System.out.println(ch + " : " + upperCase[ch - 'A']);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

my output is giving me something on the lines of:

```
R : 10
O : 6
L : 7
L : 8
R : 11
T : 5
R : 12
```

I just need to ONLY print the R: 12

How do you go by doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
   I'm new to the indentations on this site and was trying to be quick...

Comment: First you'll want to fix your code indentation so that it is readable and debuggable for you and for us. Trust me, good indentation and code formatting will make it easier for you to understand your own code and fix your own bugs since it makes it easier to understand what code is in what block.

Comment: You've edited your post, good, but the end curly brace must match the opening line's indentation as that will tell you that your code on the same line is in the same block.  Hang on....

Comment: Please see edited code to see what I am talking about. These changes may seem trivial to you at first, but please trust me, they're not. They can make or break you and your understanding of your code. The formatting shows that your code does not in fact produce the result that you had showed us previously, that it in fact prints out an interim result *inside* of the loop, something that you *don't* want to do.

Comment: Thank you dude. I can see it now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use of [Arrays#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort) method to find max or min number in the array.

```
Arrays.sort(upperCase);
int maxIndex = upperCase.length-1;
System.out.println("Max element is:"+(char)upperCase[maxIndex])+":"+upperCase[maxIndex]);
```

`sort()` method sorts the array in ascending order.Then the first element of array is `min` number and last element of array is `max`.

Note : The above code should be after the while loop so that it prints only one time instead of multiple times as in your case.

Comment: This does not work. `ch` is not accessible after the while loop. And the array index of `upperCase` is a reference to the letter. After sorting you now the biggest number but you no longer know to which letter this number refers.

Comment: @BetaRide yes. I forgot that thing.I have corrected my answer now.Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Your code compiles now, but still does not work. `(Char)upperCase[maxIndex])` does not return the character you are looking for. It returns the character coresponding to the maximum value. After all you cannot use Arrays#sort. It will find the higest value in the array, but after sorting you have no way of knowing wich character this is.

Comment: @BetaRide But the OP wants to print only the `character coresponding to the maximum value`.So isn't it right..

Comment: Yes, but your code prints the charachter representation of the max number, not the character with the max number of ocurences. The information of the later is lost by `Arrays.sort` since the position in the array actually represnts the character (`upperCase[ch - 'A']`). But `Arrays.sort` moves the elements in the array (the number of occurences) to other postions in the array. This way you no longer know which character has the highest number.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can count maximum inside your for loop. Please run my code.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
      String str = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println(str);

      int upperCaseCounter = 0;

      int upperCase[] = new int[26];
      int max=0;
      char let='A';
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         String s = scanner.nextLine();
         for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
                    if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                        upperCase[ch - 'A']++;
//                        System.out.println(ch + " : " + upperCase[ch - 'A']);
                        if(max<upperCase[ch - 'A']){
                            max=upperCase[ch - 'A'];
                            let=ch;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println(let+"   "+max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable eg MaxVal inside the while loop after a character has been incremented. Then use an if statement to compare the newly assigned incremented value (upperCase[ch-'A']) to the variable MaxVal. If it is bigger than MaxVal, assign MaxVal the value of upperCase[ch-'A']

You would probably make MaxVal a 2 dimensional array to hold the character and its current count

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep two local variable int temp  and char ch1 to track your max length and corresponding correcter . here i am giving the modified code .
package com.mindtree.programs;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ReadScacnner {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
    int upperCase[] = new int[26];
    int temp = 0;
    char ch1 = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                    upperCase[ch - 'A']++;
                    if (temp < upperCase[ch - 'A']) {
                        ch1 = ch;
                       temp = upperCase[ch - 'A'];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(upperCase);
    System.out.println("Max element is:" + ch1 + " : "
            + upperCase[upperCase.length - 1]);
}
```

}

Comment: it works! thanks! now will this work when you are trying to find lowercase letters a well??? if so, how would you implement that?

Comment: just replace isUpperCase to isLowerCase that's all.